# Magento 2 search query Customization

Tags: magento2.3, search, catalogsearch, advanced-search

I am facing an issue in search Magento 2.4.
I want to change the search behavior
For example:
I search RP-4 then getting products that contained **RP-4** string.

Then I search RP4 result **No record Found**

I want to get the same result as **RP-4** against **RP4**

Comment: are you using elasticsearch?

Comment: @RizwanKhan I did not change anything in the project search

Comment: you are using magento2.3 or magento 2.4?

Comment: go to store-> configuration -> catalog -> catalog -> catalog search .. and check what is selected in `Search Engine` ?

Comment: @RizwanKhan Magento version is 2.4.1 and Search engine is elasticsearch 7.0

Answer (score 0):

You can change the following settings and verify the search again.

please login into admin and go to the below path

`store-> configuration -> catalog -> catalog -> catalog search`

Set the `Minimum Terms to Match` to **100%**

run the indexer command from your Magento web root.

`bin/magento i:rei`

and verify the search again on the frontend.

more information can be found [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-minimum-should-match.html)

Comment: No it's not helpfull